# Bind input fields to buttons within ngFor loops | Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I am trying to create some number inputs in a form with + and - buttons next to them which can increase/decrease the number  values. I am creating the inputs and the buttons with *ngFor loops using values stored in a couple of arrays.

However I can't figure out a way to bind the inputs to buttons that are also created in the same *ngFor loops. I keep running into this error -- `Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`

I have tried using ngModel and just binding with `[value]`. I get the same error either way.

Is there another way to do this?

Stackblitz demo -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3gkrq

Code that I have tried --

```html
  <div class="border rounded p-4 m-1" *ngFor="let type of types">
    <div *ngFor="let subType of subTypes[type]">
      <label for="{{subType}}SlotsInput">{{type | titlecase}} : {{subType}}</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">-</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" (click)="(type+subType)++">+</button>
        </div>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" id="{{subType}}SlotsInput"  min="0" max="10" [name]="type+subType" [(ngModel)]="type+subType">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

--

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  types = ["dog", "horse", "hen", "elephant"];
  subTypes = {
    dog:["labrador", "vizsla"],
    horse:["arabian","shire","belgian"],
    hen:["plymouth rock", "leghorn", "bramha"],
    elephant:["african", "asian"]
  };
```

Edit: Incase it isn't clear, I want the + and - buttons to increase/decrease the number in the input field next to them.

Comment: I think you have to use form builder to do this. How can i reproduce your error?

Comment: Try binding with ngModel in the stackblitz demo to see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `ngModel` you have allow bind input to something. Your input must be inside `form` tag which angular transform into his own special form.
Wrap your inputs in form and add `#f="ngForm"`

```html
 <form id="form-group" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="border rounded p-4 m-1" *ngFor="let type of types">
      <div *ngFor="let subType of subTypes[type]">
        <label for="{{subType}}SlotsInput">{{type | titlecase}} : {{subType}}</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
            type="button" (click)="decrement(inpt)">-</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
            type="button" (click)="increment(inpt)">+</button>
          </div>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" id="{{subType}}SlotsInput"  min="0" max="10" [name]="type+subType" [value]="type+subType" ngModel #inpt="ngModel">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

in component.ts:

```js
//[...]
export class AppComponent  {
  types = ["dog", "horse", "hen", "elephant"];
  subTypes = {
    dog:["labrador", "vizsla"],
    horse:["arabian","shire","belgian"],
    hen:["plymouth rock", "leghorn", "bramha"],
    elephant:["african", "asian"]
  };

  onSubmit(form){
    console.log(form.form.value);
  }

  increment(input){
    input.control.setValue(parseInt( (input.control.value) || 0 ) +1 );
    console.log(input.control.value);
  }

  decrement(input){
    input.control.setValue(parseInt( (input.control.value) || 0 ) -1 );
    console.log(input.control.value);
  }

}
```

[stackblitz forked example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smoaek)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The stackblitz example doesn't work for me. See the edit note in my question.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad I understood it wrong that you have trouble just to bind to make it work